# Splitting strings by first instance of pattern R

Tags: r

I have a string

```
string <- "You know that song Mary had a little lamb? Mary is my friend."
```

I'd like to split it such that

```
> string[1]
[1] "You know that song "
> string[2]
[1] " had a little lamb? Mary is my friend."
```

I want to split it on the first instance of "Mary".

Closer to my actual problem, suppose I had the following string:

```
string <- "Name:      Mary
           Some stuff about Mary goes here, for a page
           Name:      Mary
           There's more stuff about her.
           Name:      Sue
           Now the name is different. I want to split on Sue here.
           Name:      Sue
           Sue appears again, but because the name is Sue again I don't want to splt.
           Name:      Beth
           The name changed again, so I want to split on Beth above (following Name: ).
           Name:      Amy
           The name changed again and now I want to split on the 'Amy' immediately following Name: ."
```

Essentially, I want to split this document so that each element corresponds to information about one person so that:

```
> string
[1] "Name:      Mary\n               Some stuff about Mary goes here, for a page\n               Name:      Mary\n               There's more stuff about her.\n               Name:      "                                            
[2] "Sue\n               Now the name is different. I want to split on Sue here.\n               Name:      Sue\n               Sue appears again, but because the name is Sue again I don't want to splt.\n               Name:      "
[3] "Beth\n               The name changed again, so I want to split on Beth above (following Name: ).\n               Name:      "                                                                                                    
[4] "Amy\n               The name changed again and now I want to split on the 'Amy' immediately following Name: ."
```

Comment: `strsplit(string,"Mary")`. I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: You can try replacing the first ocurrence with a string (that doesn't appear anywhere else) and then do the split: `strsplit(sub("Mary", "_", string), "_")`

Comment: Is there a way to automatically replace the first occurrence with a wildcard? What I'm ultimately trying to do is split a very long string using a while loop. Split on a name, if the name is the same as the previous name do nothing until a name appears that is different than the name immediately preceding it. The string is very long and I don't want to manually search through it and replace names

Comment: Suppose if there are multiple occurrence of multiple names, can you show how it would be split up?  I would also guess that the regex needs to split up if for example `had` or `a` repeats >1 time

Comment: @src471  Suppose if the string is `"You know that song Mary had a little lamb? Mary is my friend and she is also a friend of another friend"`, what will be the expected result?

Comment: @akrun I would like it to split as  "You know that song " and " had a little lamb? Mary is my friend and she is also a friend of another friend"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
regmatches(string, regexpr("Mary", string), invert = TRUE)
```

Comment: But how do you prevent the split on the second occurrence of "Mary" in this case using `strsplit`?

Comment: Sorry, didn't check the string earlier while commented.  Wrong number :-)

Comment: You could use `library(stringi);stri_split_fixed(string, 'Mary', n=2)`

Comment: I think the question is also to automatically grab these multiple occurences instead of manually entering the names

Comment: @akrun That post in your first comment is really interesting. But I think the solution above might be close to equivalent if not faster given that you'd need to piece the `strsplit()` pieces back together to get the OP's desired output? Granted I haven't benchmarked it to verify, just my impression given the differences between the desired outcomes in this question and the other you link to.  Ahh, too fast on your edit, but I do like the `stringi` solution too, upvoted.

Comment: @ForrestR.Stevens  Thanks for the comment. It was for a different purpose, but as I discussed in that, the `regmatches` seemed very slow.  It took almost 1 hour or so with system.time and still didn't complete.  For this problem, I think the OP wants it to be automatic

Comment: stringi was incorporated into my loop and it worked beautifully! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

May be this helps

```
strsplit(string, '(\\b\\S+\\b)(?=.*\\b\\1\\b.*)', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
##[1] "You know that song "                   
#[2] " had a little lamb? Mary is my friend."
```

Another case

```
string1 <- "You know that song Mary had a little lamb? Mary is my friend and she is also a friend of another friend"
strsplit(string1, '(\\b\\S+\\b)(?=.*\\b\\1\\b.*)', perl=TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "You know that song " " had "               " little lamb? Mary "
#[4] " my "                " and she is also a " " of another friend"
```

NOTE: I am not sure whether this is the way the OP wants to split for the second example.

Comment: Will this also work in my second string in the original question (edited since this was answered)? I know nothing of Perl.

Comment: @src471 Can you update your post with the expected result for your second string